# How to loop with in the feature file in karate

Tags: karate

Hi i am trying to loop a List of Map in a feature file, below is my code

```
test.feature
Feature:
 Background: 
   * def jsonPathTest = Java.type('com.test.utility.FileUtility').getNames()

 Scenario:
   * def jsonName = karate.get('jsonPathTest[' + __loop + ']')
```

Getting below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: karate.get('jsonPathTest[' + __loop + ']')
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:115)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "__loop" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
```

If i am calling another feature file with data its working:

```
test.feature
Feature:
 Background: 
   * def jsonPathTest = Java.type('com.test.utility.FileUtility').getNames()

 Scenario:
   * call read('test2.feature') jsonPathTest

test2.feature
 Feature:
  Scenario:
     * print __arg
```

But i want to loop with in the feature file only instead of calling another feature file and passing data. Please suggest me how can i do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I don't understand why you have this reluctance to use a second feature file to loop. Actually it promotes re-use and Karate has good support for this.

If you really insist, you have to use the Cucumber "native" way of looping which is called a `Scenario Outline`. Here is the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-cucumber-way

Note that the disadvantage is that you can't have a dynamic number of rows. Which seems to be what you are trying to do. If you have a dynamic number of rows *and* you want to use a single feature file, that is not supported in Karate.

EDIT: it is now supported in Karate, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

For a comparison between the two approaches in code, refer this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature